# Running multiple Rspec files in parallel with Selenium Grid

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, rspec

I have been working on a Rspec/Selenium Webdriver test framework where I need to run my Rspec tests distributed across multiple files in same directory spec/*_test.rb.I was looking for the existing solutions available and stumbled upon deep test gem (https://github.com/qxjit/deep-test) which helps driving the tests in parallel leveraging selenium grid but I was not able to implement it based on the documentation available and looks like there is no active development going on with it.Are there any ported version of deep test available to work with RSpec > 2.0.

I also looked into parallel_tests (https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) but not sure how we can use it for running multiple process on the same cpu with each process running a different rSpec test.

Here is a snippet from one of my spec file,

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'../support/Setup')
require 'rspec'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'../support/spec_helper')
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'../support/Helper')


describe "Test", :type => :selenium do

  it "should search for flights" do
     airline.home_page.queryFlight('oneWay', 'ATL', 'ORD', 'today')
  end

  it "should list all the flight results and select one flight" do
     airline.flight_list_page.selectFlight
  end
end
```

Similarly i have other spec files which I am trying to run in parallel.